# i can't get rid of my android mannager lock

Tags: lock-screens

yesterday i lost my phone, but i used android mannager to track it,put a message on the screen to that i know the location and to put a lock on it.
Today i went to where google showed me my phone was located and went and got my phone back.Only i can't get rid of the lock, first it just ask's for my pin when that is correct it ask's for the google password i had to pick with android mannager,but when i enter that one correct as wel it shows me the message i entered with android mannager while the phone is stil locked. if anyone knows what i need to do and can help me is verry appriciated. sry for the spelling, i speak dutch.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into recovery and do a full wipe and login with another google account. Did you sent a lock request with android device manager. Make sure you are entering the correct pin and the password combo. Can you be more specific about the part which comes after you enter the pin which you gave with android device manager.!! Hope this helps